# Why i am getting error failed to get properties in status 'lightdm.service'

Tags: software-installation

Failed to get properties: Transport endpoint is not connected

this error i am getting when type systemctl status lightdm.service

Comment: You've not provided any OS/release, or background details, thus you're somewhat requiring us to *guess* as we don't know what software stack you're using.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.